# Custom Drawable does not properly display in ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I'm working on an Android app that needs to display some dynamically generated images.  I've tried to implement that by creating an activity that (1) creates a customized Drawable object and (2) shows the Drawable scaled to fit and centered in an ImageView.  My problem is that when I run the app on my test device, the image shows up as a horizontal line rather than as the properly rectangular image it ought to be.  I don't know what's going on.  I'm hoping that I've just mis-specified the layout somehow.

Here's the Java code:

```
public abstract class InstructionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Constants {

    public static final int DIAGRAM_SCALE = 50;

    Instructions instructions;
    TextView     instructionsView;
    ImageView    diagramView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_instructions);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int number = intent.getIntExtra(ShapeActivity.NUMBER,1);
        double[] measurements = intent.getDoubleArrayExtra(ShapeActivity.MEASUREMENTS);
        instructions = instructions(number,measurements);
        instructionsView = findViewById(R.id.instructionsTextView);
        diagramView = findViewById(R.id.diagramView);
        instructionsView.setText(instructions.getText());
        diagramView.setImageDrawable(instructions.getDiagram());

    }

    public abstract Instructions instructions(int number, double[] measurements);

}
```

```
public class RectangleInstructionsActivity extends InstructionsActivity {

    @Override
    public Instructions instructions(int number, double[] measurements) {

        Instructions output = new Instructions();
        // Various calculations omitted for brevity
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Text generation omitted for brevity
        output.setText(sb.toString());

        // Diagram-producing block

        final float diagramWidth = (float)(BOLT*DIAGRAM_SCALE);
        final float diagramHeight = (float)(f[orientation]*DIAGRAM_SCALE);
        Drawable diagram = new Drawable() {

            @Override
            public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

                canvas.drawRect(0,0,diagramWidth,diagramHeight,output.getBackground()); // Test rectangle

            }

            // Other Drawable methods omitted for brevity

        };
        diagram.setBounds(0,0,(int)Math.ceil(diagramWidth),(int)Math.ceil(diagramHeight));
        output.setDiagram(diagram);

        // Output

        return output;

    }

}
```

And here's the XML layout for the ImageView, which is set inside a ConstraintLayout:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/diagramView"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
     android:contentDescription="@string/diagram_description"
     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/instructionsTextView"
     app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/screen_background_light" />
```

Help and suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: add image with your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, it seems that the solution--or one solution, anyway--is to specify `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` for the ImageView in the activity's xml file.